# How to colour the links by different group in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, social-networking

I'm trying to play with d3 network and there is an very interesting example in [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). It shows the relationship between different groups by different colours. Now I'm thinking to change it by coloring the links. Ideally, I want the link color to be different by different groups. Can I achieve that by modifying the js code provided in that link?

Thanks in advance really keen to know the answer.

Comment: possibly relevant: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? http://bl.ocks.org/maurizzzio/37569cdc0ed9fee40ba3

Relevant changes:

1) the `stroke` holds the color for a line, each link has info of the source/target nodes, to check that they belong to the same group the following check must be made: `graphs.nodes[d.source].group === graphs.nodes[d.target].group` but the force layout is changing the structure of `graphs.links` when the invoked, I could access the group using `d.source.group` and `d.target.group`, now if both groups are the same then the stroke of the line is the same as the color of source/target node

2) if not then the link is between nodes that belong to different groups, a class is added to each of these links to apply a grey stroke

```
.attr('stroke', function (d) {
  if (d.source.group === d.target.group) {
    return color(d.source.group);
  } else {
    d3.select(this).classed('different-groups', true);
  }
})
```

css:

```
.different-groups {
  stroke: #999;
}
```